# How to find out the null value in a vector with type of string?

Tags: dolphindb

The table structure is as follows:

```py
a = "a" NULL "b"
b = 1 2 3
t = table(a, b)
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
|  | 2 |
| b | 3 |

The data type of column a is string. I want to find the null values in a. The SQL statement is as follows:

```py
select * from t where a = NULL
```

But I get an error, how should I write a correct SQL statement?

```py
Both arguments for character comparison must have the category of LITERAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of column is string, the NULL value in the column is also in string type. So you need to convert the type. Here's some example code:

```py
select * from t where a=string(NULL)
```

The result is:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2 |